# Android string resource from database

Tags: android, localization, android-resources

I'm searching for a workaround to replace string resource (strings.xml) whit the content of an SQLite table. The content of the table is changing, and `synchronized` whit an online database. So when I modify some text on the server, they should be changed also in the app, while running.

I don't want to set every single textview's and other texts pragmatically, or create custom textview etc.

Is it possible to generate xml from that database table and use it as string resource? (In run time of course and the generated xml would be exactly the same as the original, except of the string values, so the keys wont changes)
Or does anybody have an idea to solve this problem?

Comment: Not possible. Unless, of course, if your app decompiles itself > overwrites strings.xml with the new values > recompiles and copies itself to `/data/app/` and then force reboots the target.

Comment: OK, that was just an idea of mine, but other any other way?

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to change the strings.xml file on the fly. What you can do is to abstract string gathering.

```
class YourUtilites {

    static HashMap<String, String> dbCache = new HashMap<String, String>();
    public static String getString(Context context, String key, String defaultID) {
        String value = null;

        value = dbCache.get(key);

        if (value == null) {
            // Check if the key exists in the database
            String value = db.somedbFunctionToGetString(key);
            if (value != null) {
                dbCache.put(key, value);
            }
        }

        if (value == null) {
            // If value is not in the database, resort to the default value
            value = context.getResources().getString(defaultID);
        }

        return value;
    }
}
```

Then you can use it in the textviews like this

```
textView.setText(YourUtilities.getString("dbKey", R.id.defaultValue1, this);
textView2.setText(YourUtilities.getString("dbKey2", R.id.defaultValue2, this);
...
```

This way you can update your db values and have it show up immediately. Don't forget to clear the dbCache when you update the database values. This solution obvious goes without saying that db accesses are slow so keep that in mind.

Hope this helps.